# How to input data from a userform into a selected cell - Excel

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm a noob in excel VBA so please do understand.

I am tasked to input employee total working time into a worksheet efficiently to minimize human error. So there is three option, normal working time is  490 minutes, over time is 640 minutes and user input option as sometimes the employee do not work for 490 or 640 minutes.

So I've created a userform, in my userform, i have input 2 option button for the normal working time and over time. I have also input a textbox for the third option to the user to input a specific working time.

Therefore, I wanted to open up the userform when click on a cell instead of a button. And input the data from the userform into the selected cell. I'm able to open up the userform by clicking on the cell, using this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H10:I29")) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

My issues is I do not know how to input the data from the userform into the selected cell.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Within the form, you can have a button, say _Apply_, which triggers the assignment of the correct value to a cell. To perform the actual assignment, check [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59382/assigning-value-to-cells-with-excel-vba) example.

Comment: show your userform code

Comment: I totally don't understand the link provided by FDavidov. I don't see how it could link to my issue.

I don't have any codes in my userform code, I'm clueless how to code it - user359856

Comment: show the image of your userform, and corresponding controls names

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have, in your `UserForm1`:

- `Button1`, which applies 1st value into selected cell
- `Button2`, which applies 2nd value into selected cell
- `TextBox1`, where you write an uncommon value
- `Button3`, which applies value from `TextBox1` into selected cell

In `UserForm1` code you put:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Selection.Value = 490
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Selection.Value = 640
End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click()
    Selection.Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- normal time OptionButton named after "NormalTime_OB"
- over time OptionButton named after "OverTime_OB"
- specific time TextBox named after "SpecificTime_TB"
- ok Button named after "Ok_Btn"

you may try the following code in your userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Ok_Btn_Click()
    Const NORMALHOURS As Long = 490
    Const OVERTIMEHOURS As Long = 640
    Dim hours As Long

    With Me
        Select Case True
            Case .NormalTime_OB
                hours = NORMALHOURS
            Case .OverTime_OB
                hours = OVERTIMEHOURS
            Case Else
                hours = GetTextBoxInpt(.SpecificTime_TB)
        End Select
        If hours > 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Value = hours
            .Hide
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function GetTextBoxInpt(TB As MSForms.TextBox)
    Const MINHOURS As Long = 490 '<--| change it to your needs
    Const MAXHOURS As Long = 640 '<--| change it to your needs
    Dim hours As Long

    With TB
        If IsNumeric(.text) Then
            hours = CLng(.text)
            If hours <= MINHOURS Or hours > MAXHOURS Then
                MsgBox "You must enter a value between " & MINHOURS & " and " & MAXHOURS, vbExclamation, "Working Time input"
            Else
                GetTextBoxInpt = hours
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value", vbExclamation, "Working Time input"
        End If
        .text = ""
    End With
End Function
```

while your worksheet event handler becomes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H10:I29")) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Show
        Unload UserForm1
    End If
End Sub
```